# Random Module has not attribute 'choices'

Tags: python, module

I am using Sublime Text3. I am encountering a problem with the `choices` attribute with the `random` module. I do not have the same name in any path or directory. The other attributes of random work just fine.

```
import random
import string

letters = string.ascii_lowercase
print(letters)
gen = random.choices(letters, k=16)
print(gen)
```

Here is the error code:

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/anon/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/User/test.py", line 6, in <module>
    gen = random.choices(letters)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'choices'
```

What are the common causes of this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no `random.choices` in Python 2. You can use `random.sample` in Python 2.

```
gen = random.sample(letters, k=16)
```

`random.choices` is included in Python 3

Comment: Thanks for the replacement for choices

Answer (score 3):

It would seem you are using a version of Python that is older than 3.6 which is when `random.choices` was introduced. You can see it listed at the bottom of this function description [here](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/random.html#random.choices)

You can verify your version by running

```
import sys
sys.version
```

Comment: Thank you for that. I have just checked my version of python that Sublime is using. Python 2.7. My mistake, I am using Python 3 in PyCharm and havent thought to change it..school boy error 101 :)

Comment: Thanks, I just used the CLI for `python --version` that is set as default that Sublime was using. I was going to remove it but apparently a lot of the software on Ubuntu uses python 2  files

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error when I used Python 2.7.

As a workaround, I simply used `random.choice` instead of `random.choices`, in a way as

```
foo = [random.choice(my_list) for _ in range(50)]
```

Although we do not have `random.choices` in Python 2.7, we have `random.choice`  (the former is multiple choices with duplicates, while the latter single choice).